# How to attach a blur event for @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

i have a datepicker and i want to get the value if the user modify the datepicker manually without exit the datepicker.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So do you want the value whenever someone changes the value or the value that is posted by the user in the end?

if not you could do something like:

```
 function onDatePickerChange() {
            var DateVal = $(".classofdatepicker").val();
        }
```

If you want to post this to the page you should:

```
  function checkMaySend() {
  var url = "/MyVeryOwn/UrlIPostTo";
  var DateVal = $(".classofdatepicker").val();
   var data = {  DatePickerValue: DateVal};
  }

  var jqxhr = $.post(url, data, function () {
  //Do something on post here if needed
  })
```

Comment: i want the value whenever someone changes the datepicker manually(without using the button calendar)

Comment: @Hamza I showed you how to get the value, Put that value in an onchange on the HTML element and you should have it.

Comment: this is my telerik comosant <td>@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.DateRecherche).Max(DateTime.Today).Events(e => e.Change("LancerRecherche")))</td>  if users type date without exiting the composant i want the get the value typed when i submit

Comment: @Hamza I showed you the exact javascript to post and submit the value

Answer (score -1):

this is my telerik comosant `<td>@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.DateRecherche).Max(DateTime.Today).Events(e => e.Change("LancerRecherche")))</td>` if users type date without exiting the composant i want the get the value typed when i submit .